# Tabu won't left align

Tags: tables, tabu

I am having some problems with my table where the entries seem to not be left aligning. I define the table in the following way

```
\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\caption{Image label frequency}
\label{tab-1}       % Give a unique label
\begin{tabu}to 0.45\textwidth {|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|X[l]|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\\hline
0.36 & 0.44 & 0.48 & 0.42 & 0.24 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 0.15 & 0.24 & 0.10 & 0.08 & 0.10 & 0.06 \\\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
```

However this generates the following table:

[image]

The entries aren't contained in their cells and obviously difficult to read. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! apparently cells' contents are to wide to be fit in cells nicely.  you should enlarge table width and try to reduce `\tabcolsep`. please, extend your code sniped to complete small document beginning with `\documentclas{...}`, following relevant packages (for page layout and table seting) in preamble, your table in document body and ending with `\end{documen}`. without this document is difficult to help you.

Comment: Be careful when using tabu. Read the readme and the open issues here: https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're writing a two-column document, judging from `0.45\textwidth`. Even with `\scriptsize`, with a 10pt main font size and Times font, a three digit number containing the decimal period occupies 12.25pt.

You have also fourteen times the `\arrayrulewidth` and the whole lot takes (excluding intercolumn spaces) 165pt. In a standard two-column `article` class, the column width is 229.5pt and this leaves less than 2.5pt for the intercolumn space.

So you have to reduce the intercolumn space. I show how to do it, but also a different method that avoids computations; without vertical rules, the table is much better and easier to read.

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tabu} % for the first table

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h!]
\scriptsize
\caption{Image label frequency}
\label{tab-1}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.4pt}

\begin{tabu} to \columnwidth{ | *{13}{X[c]|} }
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
\hline
0.36 & 0.44 & 0.48 & 0.42 & 0.24 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 0.15 & 0.24 & 0.10 & 0.08 & 0.10 & 0.06 \\
\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\scriptsize
\caption{Image label frequency}
\label{tab-1-again}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% let TeX compute widths
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{13}{c}}
\toprule
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 \\
\midrule
0.36 & 0.44 & 0.48 & 0.42 & 0.24 & 0.17 & 0.11 & 0.15 & 0.24 & 0.10 & 0.08 & 0.10 & 0.06 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]